# Under what conditions is it safe to do I/O operations (move/replace) on a lucene index (compass)

Tags: java, lucene, io, indexing, compass-lucene

Sometimes there is need to re-build a lucene-index from scratch. As I do not want the index to be incomplete for several hours while building, I am using a separate compass instance to build the new index and replace it in the filesystem afterwards.
Before doing so, all compass instances are stopped using `SearchEngineIndexManager#stop()`, afterwards they are restarted using `SearchEngineIndexManager#start()`

However, every now and then, the index seems to get corrupted during this operations.

Is it not safe to replace an index in the filesystem when the SearchEngineIndexManger is stopped?
Are there any other necessary precautions to consider if I need to operate on a lucene index in the file system?

Comment: BTW: I assume that the problem could be caused by not clearing the index manager's cache after re-starting it. I will do some testing and let you know whether it helped.
Having a look at http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Search-Engine/compass-2.0/org/compass/gps/impl/SingleCompassGps.java.htm#doIndex might help, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by adding 5 seconds of `sleep` after stopping and before re-starting the `IndexManager`. Might be an ugly solution, but works for me.

To be sure, I have also added a call to SearchEngineIndexManager#clearCache() after re-starting.

Answer (score 0):

What about putting your server into read-only mode then start a reindex on a *second* lucene instance (that has its own index). When finished indexing, shutdown all servers and give the new index to your main lucene sever.

Comment: Well, this sounds quite similar to what I am currently doing - but the step "giving the new index" seems to cause corruptions sometimes even though the SearchEngineIndexManager is stopped before doing so...

Comment: I have successfully used backed-up indexes. Maybe check that the config files are exactly the same, especially `schema.xml`